# Cannot read jpeg binary data, buffer only has 4 bytes of data

Tags: c, buffer, jpeg, fread

I am trying to read the JPEG file and store it in a buffer in C as part of the header of HTTP POST request, then use HTTP POST to upload to the server. But seems that it only reads the first 4 bytes of image data because on the server side I only get the first 4 hex characters of the image. What is wrong with my code? The OS is LINUX.

I realize that on the fifth HEX of the IMAGE, its 0x00, which i think C interprets it as the terminator, or it just thinks the file stops right here... How to avoid this issue?

```
unsigned long fileLen;
char *buffer;

if ((fp = fopen(filename, "rb")) == NULL){
    printf("File could not be opened\n");
    exit(1);
}else{
     fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
     fileLen=ftell(fp);
     fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
     buffer=(char *)malloc(fileLen);
     fread(buffer, fileLen, 1, fp);
     fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(buffer)` is pointer(char*) size.

Answer (score 1):

`buffer` is a `char *`, pointer to a char, so you get the size of a pointer on your machine (4 bytes, you are running on 32-bit, right?).

The return value from `fread` is the number of bytes read, I suggest you use that.

`0x00` is only a delimiter in C for strings, it is not relevant in this case.

By the way, you might wish to consider putting-in some error handling.  If `ftell` failed it would return -1, which you then use in your `malloc`.  This would then fail and return NULL, which you would use in your `fread` as the first argument.  That will give you a SIGSEGV Segmentation Violation, i.e. crash your program.

Edit:  another issue might be if you have a very large file.  You seek to end-of-file to get its size (consider using `fstat` instead) but what if the file size exceeds your maximum heap size?  For example a 2 gigabyte file?  That will cause `malloc` to fail and return NULL.

Comment: I don't want to be negative here, but strictly speaking, technically there is no such thing as *the size of a pointer*. There is nothing stopping pointers to different types having different sizes, although that is very rare nowadays. To be technically correct, he really is getting the size of a pointer to char on his machine - although, of course, there is an upper bound in the size of every pointer, that's why casting between `void *` and any other pointer type is safe (and the same for `char *` for historical reasons).

Comment: @cdarke Hi, I have revised my question. Can you take a look one more time? I know I made a mistake to output the size of buffer, but thats not the main problem.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: accepted, and of course in theory it is dependant on the compiler implementation.  However such details are probably not helpful to the OP.

Comment: @HughH:  You describe your problem as being that you only have 4 bytes in the buffer.  Are you saying that this is still the case?  How do you know?  Check the return value from `fread`.

Comment: @HughH: sorry, I only just noticed this was part of an HTML request.  Check the header, are you sending this as text or jpeg?

Comment: @cdarke btw the jpeg image is only 30k