# Cannot read .jpg binary data, buffer only has 4 bytes of data

Tags: c++, io, fread

My question almost exactly the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263846/cannot-read-jpeg-binary-data-buffer-only-has-4-bytes-of-data) which is unanswered. I am trying to read the binary data of a .jpg to send as an HTTP response on a simple web server using C++. The code for reading the data is below.

```
FILE *f = fopen(file.c_str(),"rb");
if(f){
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
    int length = ftell(f);
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
    char* buffer = (char*)malloc(length+1);
    if(buffer){
      int b = fread(buffer,1,length,f);
      std::cout << "bytes read: " << b << std::endl;
    }
    fclose(f);
    buffer[length] = '\0';
    return buffer;
  }
  return NULL;
```

When the request for the image is made and this code runs, fread() returns 25253 bytes being read, which seems correct. However, when I perform strlen(buffer) I get only 4. Of course, this gives an error on a browser when the image tries to display. I have also tried manually setting the HTTP content length to 25253 but I then a receive a curl error 18, indicating the transfer ended early (as only 4 bytes exist).

As the other poster mentioned in their question, the 5th byte of the image (and I assume most .jpg images) is 0x00, but I am unsure if this has an effect on saving to the buffer.

I have verified the .jpg images I am loading are in the directory, valid, and display properly when opened normally. I have also tried 2 different methods of loading the binary data, and both also give only 4 bytes, so I am really at a loss. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read jpeg binary data, buffer only has 4 bytes of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263846/cannot-read-jpeg-binary-data-buffer-only-has-4-bytes-of-data)

Comment: a .jpg is not a string, so it does not make sense to use strlen() on it.

Comment: I  am doing strlen() on the buffer after I read the data, which is a char*.

Comment: nos is simply right, you have the right amount, but `strlen` does not make sense, since it will only count up to the first 0 byte.

Comment: I was using strlen() on the char* buffer, which is returned by that function, to see its length (4). Not on a .jpg. Regardless, when I set the content length of the HTTP response to 25253, the error message indicates only 4 bytes were read before no more data could be read.

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: `buffer[length] = '\0';` also makes no sense, ditch it. Your buffer is not a null-terminated string. Call `malloc(length)`, not `malloc(length+1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the request for the image is made and this code runs, fread()
> returns 25253 bytes being read, which seems correct. However, when I
> perform strlen(buffer) I get only 4.

Well there is your problem: You read *binary* data, not text, meaning that special characters like newline or the null character is not a something that indicates the structure of a text, its simple numbers.

`strlen` is a function to give you the count of characters other than `'\0'` or simply `0`. However in a binary file like jpeg there a dozen of zeros usually in there, and because of a binary header structure, there seems to be always a zero at position 5 so, so `strlen` will stop at the first it found and return 4.

Also you seem confused by the fact that you try to send this "text interpreted" jpeg to a HTTP server. Of course it will complain, because you can not simply send binary data as text in HTTP, you either have to encode it, base64 is very popular, or set the content length header. Of course you also have to tell the HTTP client/server the type by setting the proper MIME header.

Comment: "you have to encode it" Not really. HTTP can send binary data just fine. You need to set the mime type correctly.

Comment: If you want to be smart you have to do it right: If you do not use a transfer encoding header then you have to use a content length header, which you forgot to mention. 3.3.  Message Body RFC 7230.

Comment: Well seems to better be safe in the zoo of different HTTP implementations and use a transfer encoding then, isn't it?

Comment: Transfer encoding has nothing to do with base64. That's Content-Transfer-Encoding header, not Transfer-Encoding. You need Content-Length regardless of Content-Transfer-Encoding. You don't need Content-Length if you use Transfer-Encoding like "chunked" or "gzip" which is a totally different beast. It has nothing to do with being "text-based", it is very much binary based.

Comment: Woops forgot that there are many headers , probably because the RFC says "Transfer-Encoding is analogous to the Content-Transfer-Encoding field
   of MIME, which was designed to enable safe transport of binary data" just after the mentioned part. However, I bet that the CURL problem the OP described could be mitigated by a base64 content transfer encoding.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. But you are right in the way that there are many headers (2 length + 1 mime length and so on) and my answer was a bit too narrow on that. Thank you. But I suppose that one can't and shouldn't handle the whole HTTP1-3 problems of content here. If you have further suggestions for answer improvement let me know.

Comment: OP shouldn't handle these problems because libcurl already handles them just fine. Just feed it correct data.